# WebRTC build with bitcode. Fails on the last step

Tags: ios, xcode, g++, clang, webrtc

Im trying to build a WebRTC framework with enabled bitcode following those instructions:

1. git clone
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git
2. export PATH=/path/to/fetched/depot_tools:$PATH
3. mkdir webrtc
4. cd webrtc
5. fetch --nohooks webrtc_ios
6. gclient sync
7. cd webrtc/src
8. tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py --bitcode --arch arm64 x64 arm

[link](https://boramaapps.medium.com/ios-building-webrtc-from-source-with-bitcode-enabled-c8757d78c748)

7 steps done successfully. But the next step is:
**tools_webrtc/ios/build_ios_libs.py --bitcode --arch arm64 x64 arm**
fails with error:

```
clang: error: unknown argument: '-ffile-compilation-dir=.'
[18/3367] CC obj/modules/audio_coding/isac_c/arith_routines_hist.o
```

Please help me to understand whats going wrong, and how to fix it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this patch, could fix your issue:
https://aur.archlinux.org/cgit/aur.git/tree/use-ffile-compilation-dir.patch?h=ungoogled-chromium